# Multivariate Regression: Both Continuous and Categorical Predictor Variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, continuous-data, multivariate-regression, variable

I am involved in a meta-analysis assessing the role of multiple baseline characteristics (e.g. age, BMI, symptoms and signs) in a given disease.
One element of our analysis includes a multivariate regression assessment of said characteristics as predictors for outcomes related to said disease (mild, moderate, severe, deceased).

Unfortunately, the data available in public manuscripts is summary data and is split between continuous  (age, BMI; either mean+-SD or median+IQR) and categorical (symptoms and signs; n(%)).
We have contacted all of the authors and unfortunately none of them have provided us with the individual patient data.

Further reading has confirmed that we cannot combine the summary continuous variable data types due to differences in normality. However, we still may be able to use the mean+-SD data.

The questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible to use both continuous and categorical predictors together in multivariate regression analysis?
2. What software package could be used to achieve this?

**Any help would be much appreciated.**

Comment: How many different outcome / dependent variables do you have?

Comment: Dear Robert, thank you for taking the time.
We have three dependent variables (disease negative, disease mild, disease moderate-severe).
We currently have 12 categorical predictors.
We may supplement this with up to 3 continuous predictors if this is possible.
Thanks in advance.